# How DML queries execute in MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, dml

I want to know if I fire query like insert into emp ...
What are the steps involved in query ?

It will go through InnoDB buffer pool?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is way to broad to answer here.. if you really want to know it you could download and study the MySQL sourcecode..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a broad answer to your broad question.

All DMLs and `SELECTs` always goes through the buffer_pool in InnoDB.  It is a *cache* of the blocks that compose the BTrees that compose the data (organized by the necessary `PRIMARY KEY`) and each secondary `INDEX`.

For DML (broadly):

1. Fetch a block, if not already in the buffer pool.
2. Modify whatever.
3. Mark the block "dirty".
4. Rinse and repeat.
5. Eventually (as a background task), the block will be written back to disk.  Meanwhile, it is in the cache so that other operations can avoid having to fetch it from disk.

Modifying a non-unique index involves the "Change buffer".  That is sort of a "delayed write" for such changes.

`SELECTs`:

1. Fetch a block (if not already in buffer pool).
2. Fetch row(s) out of that block.
3. Rinse and repeat.

Note: in both DML and SELECT, the discovery of where a row usually involves drilling down a BTree, which involves fetching nodes (blocks) of the BTree.  They, too, are cached (and tend to live a long time in the buffer pool).

If you want more details, start another Question with more specifics.